# How to launch a pod and feed its input stream

Tags: java, kubernetes

I'm newbie to Kubernetes.
I wonder how to launch a container programmatically in Java (or Scala), and feed the input stream of the process with some binary data.  Probably I need a job.  I've found how to launch a job, but I have no control over its input stream.

I can use any convenient Kubernetes client library.

I need it to launch a [kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko#how-does-kaniko-work) container and feed its input stream with a `.tar.gz` file generated on the fly (via the `--context tar://stdin` option).

I could do an `exec` over an existing `kaniko` container, but don't know to launch the container appropriately for this purpose, because the container doesn't include any shell.

Comment: This is a little unusual in Kubernetes.  Can you launch a non-interactive pod with an HTTP server inside it, and feed it data using `curl` or another HTTP client?

Comment: `kaniko` isn't a usual `kubernetes` service like `nginx` e.g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `kubectl run` to create a pod and connect its stdin with option `-i`.
Your container should termiate gracefully when the work is done.

Example:

```
echo "echo foo" | kubectl run -i busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never
```

Reference:

https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_run/

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically with the fabric8 Java client library, it can be done in this way:

https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/doc/CHEATSHEET.md#running-a-pod

```
try (KubernetesClient client = new KubernetesClientBuilder().build()) {
    client.run().inNamespace("default")
            .withName("kaniko")
            .withImage("gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest")
            .done();
}
```

It is quite handy to set env. variables or add arguments.

Now I have to research, how to feed the standard input.